# how can i find the name of my file uploaded in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to automate my code a bit more, but for that I need my program to know the filenames,

```
uploaded1 = files.upload() 
df = pd.read_csv('Formulário sem título1.csv')
```

I already tried to do like this:

```
uploaded1 = files.upload() 
df = pd.read_csv(uploaded1)
```

But it doesn't work like that, i don't know if it's the best but i'm thinking of doing something like this:

```
uploaded1 = files.upload() 
file_name = uploaded1[filename]
df = pd.read_csv(uploaded1)
```

Comment: At least for me, `files` is not a _well-known_ object so I have no idea what the `.upload` method is doing/returning, which makes it nearly impossible to help

Comment: sorry I started studying data analysis a little while ago so I don't know much about it, I didn't put all the code in because it's huge, but I'm using pandas, that's all.

Comment: Yes, but you do need to provide the code necessary to reproduce the problem. The issue is that `files` might be a class you (or a co-worker) defined in your code somewhere, in which case no one here has any idea what it's doing or how it behaves. I did a quick check and couldn't find any obvious python objects with a `.upload` method so this seems something unique to your code

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the help, sorry i can't explain the problem well, i'm still very new to programming

Comment: what is `files`? Where did you get it? I never saw `.upload()` in any function/class in `pandas` so it has to be something different. So there is no answer for your problem. OR maybe it is some module in `Google Colabs` - then you should search in documentation for  `Google Colabs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say what is `files` and I found `files.upload()` only in `snippets` in `Google Colabs` so I assume that it is from `Google Colabs` - so it is not part of `pandas`.

`snippets` in `Google Colabs` shows that you can get filenames using `.keys()`

```
from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()

for name in uploaded.keys():
    print('filename:', name)
    print('length:', uploaded[name])
```

---

**EDIT:**

Full working code

```
from google.colab import files
import pandas as pd

uploaded = files.upload()

for name in uploaded.keys():
  print('filename:', name)
  print('length:', uploaded[name])
  df = pd.read_csv(name)
  print(df)
```

Comment: Your answer was very helpfull, thanks : )